# NA's appearing in my logistic regression summary output. How should I procede?

Tags: logistic, binomial-distribution, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc

I have been following multiple posts on this same topic and understand why I have NA's in my summary table. I am wondering what is an appropriate course of action in order to conduct a post hoc analysis on the data using R Studio.

Background:
I am conducting an experiment looking at how various factors affect insect marker detectability. Individuals were tested for marker detection only once in a process that destroys the insect (no repeated measures).

I have 3 explanatory variables, application method ("apptreat" = 2 levels), marker type ("marker" = 2 levels), and time after exposure ("exp" = 3 levels). The data is binomial with marker detection as the response variable (detec) with 1 representing the marker was detected and 0 representing the marker was not detected. All variables are categorical and classified as factors.
Based on the model, the only significant interaction was between marker and exp. I need to look at the multiple comparisons between the main effects to see how they effect marker detectability. I also need to look at the multiple comparisons within the interaction to see the specific relationship of how the detectability of each marker type is affected by time after exposure.

Model:

```
>id.glm2<-glm(detec~apptreat+marker+exp+marker*exp, family=binomial, data=indiv_detec3)

>summary(id.glm2)

Call:
glm(formula = detec ~ apptreat + marker + exp + marker * exp, 
family = binomial, data = indiv_detec3)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.2631  -0.4884  -0.2857   0.6113   3.0937  

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)       -3.1781     0.5103  -6.228 4.73e-10 ***
apptreatLitter     3.6488     0.3069  11.890  < 2e-16 ***
markerMilk         0.8109     0.6180   1.312 0.189470    
exp24             -1.5989     0.6196  -2.581 0.009862 ** 
exp48              0.9306     0.6190   1.503 0.132763    
markerMilk:exp24   1.8999     0.6751   2.814 0.004887 ** 
markerMilk:exp48   3.1068     0.8051   3.859 0.000114 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

     Null deviance: 1182.37  on 906  degrees of freedom
 Residual deviance:  610.14  on 900  degrees of freedom
AIC: 624.14

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

I would like to conduct a post hoc analysis on the data using the `glht()` function in the `multcomp` package, however it is unable to do the multiple comparisons on the interaction variable and I get a warning message that values for the main effects may not be accurate because of the presence of the interaction.

I have read that in order to fix this problem, I can add a column into the dataset representing the interaction between "marker" and "exp" (ME). I have done this and re-ran the model using the interaction column as a main effect, rather than including the interaction in the model as normal.

New model:

```
>indiv_detec3$inter_MarEx<-interaction(indiv_detec3$marker, indiv_detec3$exp)
>id.glm3<-glm(detec~apptreat+marker+exp+inter_MarEx, family=binomial, data=indiv_detec3)
> summary(id.glm3)

Call:
glm(formula = detec ~ apptreat + marker + exp + ME, family = binomial, 
data = indiv_detec3)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.2631  -0.4884  -0.2857   0.6113   3.0937  

Coefficients: (3 not defined because of singularities)
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     -3.1781     0.5103  -6.228 4.73e-10 ***
apptreatLitter   3.6488     0.3069  11.890  < 2e-16 ***
markerMilk       0.8109     0.6180   1.312 0.189470    
exp24            0.3010     0.4442   0.678 0.497994    
exp48            4.0374     0.5190   7.779 7.31e-15 ***
MEEW 24         -1.8999     0.6751  -2.814 0.004887 ** 
MEEW 48         -3.1068     0.8051  -3.859 0.000114 ***
MEMilk 0             NA         NA      NA       NA    
MEMilk 24            NA         NA      NA       NA    
MEMilk 48            NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1182.37  on 906  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  610.14  on 900  degrees of freedom
AIC: 624.14

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

I understand that since I added a column to reflect the interaction and am using that as a main effect, there is now colinearity between the "inter_MarEx" (interaction variable) and the two main effects represented in the interaction ("marker" and "exp"). This colinearity is resulting in production of NA's in the summary output and prevents me from preforming the post hoc analysis. When I do attempt the post hoc test I get an error message.

```
> summary(glht(id.glm3, linfct=mcp(inter_MarEx="Tukey")))
```

> Error in modelparm.default(model, ...) : 
>     dimensions of coefficients and covariance matrix don't match

Is it appropriate to set up 2 separate models (one with the interaction only and one with main effects only) and conduct the multiple comparisons post hoc analysis on each model separately? Should I omit the main effects "marker" and "exp" from the model `id.glm3` since they are accounted for in the interaction ("inter_MarEx")? If not, how can I proceed with conducting my post hoc multiple comparisons of all main effects and the interaction?

Comment: Since you have "time after exposure" and from the notation, I am suspicious that you might have repeated measures. If this is the case, then you need to account for that, e.g. by using a multilevel model.

Comment: This is not a repeated measures since I must destroy the insect in order to detect the marker (cannot test any individual more than once). I'll edit the question to include this bit of info.Thanks for the input though.

Comment: (1) It's queer that the call returned by `summary(id.glm3)` introduces a new variable, `ME`, but we can't check that because your code isn't runnable for lack of a data-set. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
(2) It'd help to write out mathematically the models you're attempting to fit, both to make the question more comprehensible to people who don't use R to fit their logistic regression models, & for your own understanding. (3) Assuming familiarity with the `glht` function must shrink your base of ...

Comment: ... potential answerers considerably. (4) Nonetheless, it seems clear the singular design matrix results from your introducing a new categorical variable with six levels *in addition to* the three-level & two-level categorical variables you'd already got, rather than *instead of*. Drop the "main effects", & you should be able to confirm the resulting model is the same as your first one, merely having a different parametrization.

Comment: @Scortchi Thank you. I do tend to assume that people on this forum are skilled with R, which I shouldn't do (thanks for the reminder). I am not super savvy with the math behind the statistics, so I'm sorry I cannot include that for clarity as you suggest. I edited the question to be more clear on what the ME in the second model represents. I re-ran second the model without the main effects and got very similar results (coefficients are slightly different). I just wanted verification that this is an acceptable way to proceed (since I'm pretty new to statistics). Thanks again.